# Configuring Groovy on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm using Jenkins ver 2.121.2. I'm trying to configure the Groovy plugin to run groovy scripts via a Jenkins job. The [plugin documentation provided here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy)

does not appear to match the UI I see in the System Configuration - Groovy section of this version of Jenkins. The various parameters don't match and so far I'm unable to get the plugin to run a simply groovy script. Not being familar with java and how the classpath works I'm not able to loosely interpret the instructions and get it working. If anyone can point me at documentation that more closely matches the Groovy plugin with the most current version of Jenkins I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to configure an instance (or instances) of Groovy to run scripts in your builds.  You do that on the Global Tool Configuration page.

You should have a least one JDK configured in the Global Tools Configuration (or have JAVA_HOME defined).

[image]

You can have Jenkins install the version of Groovy you want (on first use), or you can install Groovy yourself and point to it as in the example below:

[image]

Once this is in place, you can use the Execute Groovy Script build step in a build:

[image]

Comment: This definitely gets me closer, but things are still significantly out of sync.

Under Plugins I have the "Groovy" plugin installed. It just says the word "Groovy", and over on the far right it shows "2.0".

Under System Configuration there is a Groovy section that only has a single checkbox to "allow token macro processing".

Under Global Tool Configuration I can go to the Groovy section and click "Add Groovy, which then gives me a drop down to install numerous versions of Groovy. The latest is 2.5.1. But there is no "Install" button, and there is definitely no GROOVY_HOME text box.

Comment: Finally, under the job itself down in the Groovy sections there are text boxes for Groovy parameters, Class path, Script parameters, Properties, and java opts. When running the job I get the error "Environment variable JAVA_HOME has not been set." So yes, I'm closer, but I don't want to run through the full matrix of possibilities searching for the right combination of parameters.

Comment: So, you have the latest plugin. I don't have the global token macro configuration enabled - you probably don't need it either. What you see in the Global Tool Configuration depends on if you keep install automatically checked (you'll see in the screen shot above that it is 'not' checked).  It does not 'install' groovy until you have a build that actually uses it.  Finally, you should configure one or more Java JDK's to use in your builds.  (see above)

Comment: I accept this answer because I think it probably gets me as close as I can get. But, the difference between this plugin and other "click and go" plugins is vast. The fact that I should "configure one or more Java JDKs" is itself another mystery. The stack trace I saw when running Groovy is clearly coming from Java. How much more java config is necessary? I feel there is a body of knowledge here quite divorced from Jenkins itself that is required to use Groovy.